# Android Database ListView Update

Tags: java, android

My question is related to android.
so i want to create database and then i have to get that all values in the text view and after that when user want he/she can modify the database and the updated database entries has to be shown in the database.so please give me the solution of my problem of code of it.it will be very help full.

thank you

Comment: try this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: Did you try anything, post that? You can check this if not. http://androidituts.com/android-database-listview-example/